# php if empty string do something

Tags: php

I'm having trouble making a empty string to have something inside, I'm also removing some other unnecessary characters from that string which works.

```
$desc = strip_tags($mapAnnotationArray);

$mapAnnotationArrayOutput = str_replace( array('"', '(' , ')'), '', $desc);
$mapAnnotationArrayOutput = trim($mapAnnotationArrayOutput);

if(empty($mapAnnotationArrayOutput)) {
    ($mapAnnotationArrayOutput == "empty");
}
```

Comment: What's `($mapAnnotationArrayOutput == "empty");` meant to do?

Comment: Assignation is done with one equal sign.

Comment: You're comparing instead of assigning, which is most likely what you intend to do. Use `($mapAnnotationArrayOutput = "empty")`

Comment: @EM-Creations its going into a database

Comment: If the variable `$mapAnnotationArrayOutput` is going into a database, use `$mapAnnotationArrayOutput = "empty"` NOT `$mapAnnotationArrayOutput == "empty"`

Comment: optimization tip: use [trim($desc,' "()')](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) instead str_replace if only to "remove extremes".

Comment: i know its solved but actully setting it to empty rather than the word 'empty' makes more sense to me `$mapAnnotationArrayOutput = ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
($mapAnnotationArrayOutput == "empty");
```

To this

```
$mapAnnotationArrayOutput = "empty";
```

Comment: That's what he was doing wrong, yep.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen many people write:

```
if( x = "foo")
```

and wonder why it assigns `"foo"` to `x`... but never the other way around.

```
if( !$mapAnnotationArrayOutput) $mapAnnotationArrayOutput = "empty";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
print("String is empty");
```

In the if statement, at the moment `($mapAnnotationArrayOutput == "empty");` will have no output so you wouldn't know if the string was empty or not.

If you're trying to assign the variable the value of "empty", use:

`$mapAnnotationArrayOutput = "empty";`

Instead.